# reset reCAPTCHA v2 not working in react correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-google-recaptcha

when use grecaptcha.reset() after onChange in recaptcha get this error

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'clients')

when  I reload page working fine ....
is there any solution without refresh page ??

Comment: have you ever reset Captcha with ref?

Comment: yes reset with ref and still not working

Comment: please send the code you used, so that we can solve the problem better . I don't know what is clients that is undefined. unclear

Comment: and I suggest use Reaptcha instead of react-google-recaptcha . please read this comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/50846920/8460733